# having problems using python script in linux crontab

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, cron

having problems using python script in linux crontab. I'm trying to run the Wal logs postgresql cleanup script, but I'm facing a problem such that there is no tty terminal in crontab. as a result I get an error in the logs.

````
nameContainer = "postgres"

cmdGrep = f'docker exec -it {nameContainer}  /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_controldata /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ | grep REDO'
res = os.popen (cmdGrep).read()
resFilter = res.rsplit(':')
cmdGo = f'docker exec -it {nameContainer} pg_archivecleanup -d /var/lib/postgresql/10/archive {resFilter[2].strip()} '
os.system(cmdGo)


error:
the input device is not a TTY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/scripts/clearWalLogs.py", line 9, in <module>
    cmdGo = f'docker exec -it {nameContainer} pg_archivecleanup -d /var/lib/postgresql/10/archive {resFilter[2].strip()} '
IndexError: list index out of range```
````

Comment: Do you really need to allocate a pseudo-TTY for the `docker exec`? If not, remove `-it` from `docker exec` and it should be fine.

Comment: I understand that there are no values ​​in resFilter, since the problem is that crontab does not have a terminal, and the script needs to output to the terminal to get the values, as I understand it. The question is whether it can be accessed or is there a way to solve the issue

Comment: script without crontab works fine

Comment: The TTY may only needed if you are wanting to keep "STDIN" (`-i`) open for user input. However, as you only execute a command, you should be fine without `-it`, as the process should get the output nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the use of a `pseudo-TTY` for input from `STDIN`, which is invoked by the option `-t` during `docker exec`.
As the commands revoked by `docker exec` doesn't need any user input, the option `-it` can be omitted from `docker exec` and therefore the process executed without a error message.

`STDOUT` will still be captured, even without the use of `-it`.